# ChartJS (React) Line Chart - How to show single tooltip with data and labels from 3 (multiple) dataset?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, data-visualization, linechart

I am trying to show a tooltip in Line Chart when a point was hovered. The tooltip will contain 3 data from 3 different data sets and 1 Label only.

**Label:** `Date`

**Data Sets:**

```
 1. Cases
 2. Deaths
 3. Recoveries
```

This is the current output of the Line Chart that I made:

[image]

In the current output when I hover in one data set it only shows the data of the current data set only. In the image above I hovered the data set **`Cases`**.

Here's my current source code (`CasesGraph.js`):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import Chart from "./Chart";

const CasesGraph = (country) => {
let currentCountry = country.country;
const [chart, setChart] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    getData();
}, []);

 const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(
        "https://corona.lmao.ninja/v3/covid-19/historical/"+currentCountry+"?lastdays=all"
      );

  setChart({
    labels: Object.keys(res.data.timeline.cases),
    showTooltips: true,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Covid-19 Cases", //CASES DATASET
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
        borderColor: "#eb1515",
        borderCapStyle: "butt",
        borderDash: [],
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        borderJoinStyle: "miter",
        pointBorderColor: "#eb1515",
        pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 5,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#eb1515",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "#eb1515",
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 1,
        pointHitRadius: 10,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        data: Object.values(res.data.timeline.cases)
      },
      {
        label: "Covid-19 Deaths",  //DEATHS DATASET
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
        borderColor: "#1a1c1a",
        borderCapStyle: "butt",
        borderDash: [],
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        borderJoinStyle: "miter",
        pointBorderColor: "#1a1c1a",
        pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 5,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#1a1c1a",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "#1a1c1a",
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 1,
        pointHitRadius: 10,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        data: Object.values(res.data.timeline.deaths)
      },
      {
        label: "Covid-19 Recoveries", //RECOVERIES DATASET
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
        borderColor: "#0ec90e",
        borderCapStyle: "butt",
        borderDash: [],
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        borderJoinStyle: "miter",
        pointBorderColor: "#0ec90e",
        pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 5,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#0ec90e",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "#0ec90e",
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 1,
        pointHitRadius: 10,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        data: Object.values(res.data.timeline.recovered)
      }
    ],
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'label',
      callbacks: {
  
          title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
              return data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index]; //Date
          },
  
          beforeLabel: function(tooltipItem, data) {
              return '\nCases: ' + data.datasets[0].data[0] + 
                      '\nDeaths: ' + data.datasets[1].data[1] + 
                      '\nRecoveries: ' + data.datasets[2].data[2];
          },
  
          label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
              return 'Data2: ' + data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].cases[tooltipItem.index];
          },
      },
    },
  },
  );
} catch (error) {
  console.log("CasesGraph: "+ error.response);
}


};

  return (
    <div style={{ position: "relative", margin: "auto", width: "80vw"}}>
      <Chart data={chart} /> <!-- CHART COMPONENT -->
    </div>
  );
};

export default CasesGraph;
```

And here's my code for **`Chart.js`** component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";

const Chart = ({ data }) => {
  return <Line 
            data={data} 
            options={{ 
                responsive: true, 
                showTooltips: true,
                height: '600px', 
                width: "600px", 
                hover: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: false,
                },
            }}
        />;
};

export default Chart;
```

**For more clear illustration of what I am trying to achieve here's the example:** [Chart.js - Line Chart Tooltip Hover Mode](https://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/ZeaLGj)

[image]

Notice the tooltip has the two data from the two different datasets.

Comment: Did you got any solution. I am also facing the same issue. The below example is not working for me. I am using "react-chartjs-2": "^3.0.4"

Answer (score 2):

I have also been facing the same issue with react-chartjs-2 where I was unable to show multiple tooltips for **Line** **Graph**. After reading the document and trial and error, somehow I have cracked the solution.

There are three things. Need to configured with right namespace.

**1.interaction:**

```
interaction: {
              mode: "index",
              intersect: false,
            }
```

**2. tooltips:**

```
tooltips:{
     mode: "index",
     intersect: false,
 }
```

**3.Hover:**

```
 hover: {
            mode: "nearest",
            intersect: true,
          },
```

Three configuration with correct name will as below in options props.

```
 options={{
        interaction: {
          mode: "index",
          intersect: false,
        },

        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: true,
            position: "right",
            align: "start",
            labels: {
              usePointStyle: true,
              boxWidth: 6,
            },
            title: {
              display: true,
              text: "Chart.js Bar Chart",
            },
          },
          tooltips: {
            mode: "index",
            intersect: false,
          },
          hover: {
            mode: "nearest",
            intersect: true,
          },
        },
        responsive: true,
        title: {
          display: false,
        },
        scales: {
          x: {
            type: "time",
            ticks: {
              autoSkip: true,
              maxTicksLimit: 14,
            },
            time: {
              unit: "month",
              displayFormats: {
                quarter: "MMM YYYY",
              },
            },
          },
          y: {
            ticks: {
              callback: function (value, index, values) {
                return `${value}  kVA`;
              },
            },
          },
        },
      }}
```

Comment: Adding to this in 2022 - this worked perfectly for me. Only downside is the label/tooltip appears bang in the middle of the chart vertically (not horizontally, it will be in line with the data you're hovering over), rather than exactly over where you're hovering, but other than that this solution is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `tooltips` in your code and set your code - as is shown in this [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MauricioSO2021/qcghtzpw/) I made.

So, the `config` section should look like this:

```
// NOTE: "full_data" is the data source (i.e res.data, in your case).

var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: Object.keys(full_data.timeline.cases),
    showTooltips: true,
    datasets: [{
      label: "Covid-19 Cases", //CASES DATASET
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
      borderColor: "#eb1515",
      borderCapStyle: "butt",
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: "miter",
      pointBorderColor: "#eb1515",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#eb1515",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#eb1515",
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 1,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      data: Object.values(full_data.timeline.cases)
    }, {
      label: "Covid-19 Deaths", //DEATHS DATASET
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
      borderColor: "#1a1c1a",
      borderCapStyle: "butt",
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: "miter",
      pointBorderColor: "#1a1c1a",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#1a1c1a",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#1a1c1a",
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 1,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      data: Object.values(full_data.timeline.deaths)
    }, {
      label: "Covid-19 Recoveries", //RECOVERIES DATASET
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
      borderColor: "#0ec90e",
      borderCapStyle: "butt",
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: "miter",
      pointBorderColor: "#0ec90e",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#0ec90e",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "#0ec90e",
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 1,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      data: Object.values(full_data.timeline.recovered)
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js Line Chart'
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false,
    },
    hover: {
      mode: 'nearest',
      intersect: true
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Dates'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
        },
      }]
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Could you please provide solution purely for ReactJS with below version. I am using "react-chartjs-2": "^3.0.4"